# Passing complex objects via PHP

Tags: php, class, serialization, get

I've been researching a bit but I cannot find any way of doing this...

I need to **pass an instance of a complex PHP class** (formed by properties, functions, arrays, etc.) between different pages. The variable of the object is called `$Model`; **I've been trying to use the GET method and "serialize" / "unserialize"**, but I **cannot retrieve the object** in the new page...

I'm trying to pass the object as follows:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?modelobject='.serialize($Model).'">Pass Model Object</a>';
```

Then, I'm trying to retrieve it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['modelobject'])) //$_GET when used in a link!
{
    $ModelObjPost = unserialize($_GET['modelobject']); //$_GET when used in a link!
    echo "POST: Model Object retrieved<br>";
    var_dump($ModelObjPost);
}
```

**There could be some kind of problem with certain characters in the serialization** (I'm not sure, though), as the link that should send the object sometimes gets printed as (and it is also recognized as a URL):

```
r";s:3:"new";b:0;}i:2;(... MORE STUFF ...)s:9:"dbModelId";s:1:"1";}">Pass Model Object
```

Should I try a completely different approach, or this method should work, but there is just something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: why you don't use sessions?

Comment: you might need to use urldecode to get the correct string. Without knowing exactly what's going on it's hard to give you a better alternative, but this is definitely not best practice and also not secure as the user can easily modify the serialized data sent to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two best options in this case would be to either:

1. Use a `$_SESSION` variable. You could save the object as `$_SESSION['Model']` and access that on each page that you need to use it. Be sure to call `session_start();` on each of those pages to resume the session.
2. Use `urlencode(serialize($Model))` in the URL and use `urldecode()` on the next page to make sure that you don't have encoding issues in the URL. `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` would also be a good option for object to string serialization.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! Sessions seem the right way to do it, but I'm on a really tight schedule (and just implementing a prototype, so security isn't an issue right now)... I've tried the "urlencode" and it does the job, so I'll stick with it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Sounds good! Once you get past your proof of concept, you should definitely convert that to a session variable :)

Answer (score 2):

### Warning:  I would discourage serializing a class and placing the result in an end-user readable location.  This probably reveals far more about your application than you should be disclosing publicly.

---

Let's clear up some terminology right up front.  I assume you know this, but just to be clear... A class is both the code that defines the behavior you want for an object and data (properties).  An instance is when you use the `new` keyword on a class to create a usable object using that class definition.

By the very nature of how PHP works (typically), all instances are unloaded and deleted after a page loads.  It cannot survive in memory to be used on a second page.

Typically you would create a file that contains the class definition you're trying to pass between pages, and create a new instance of the class on each page.

If you're trying to keep state between pages, you should look at [using sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). **If you choose to use sessions**, and want to keep an instance of your class inside your session, keep in mind what I said above - it will be deleted and recreated between the pages.  You will need to make sure your class is set up to reload everything it needs to operate.  PHP provides for a ["magic" method to do this:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup) `__wakeup()`  in this method, you will need to restore the object back to the same state it was in on the previous page load.

---

Other ways to pass data between pages (or page loads) would be arrays for HTTP GET or POST.

```
$data = array( 1,2,3,4, 'a' => 'abcd' );
$query = http_build_query(array('aParam' => $data));
$url = 'somepage.php?data=' . $query;
```

Forms may be created to pass arrays of data by utilizing array notation in the form field names

```
<form action="somepage.php" method="post">
    <input name="option[a][]" value="option a,0">
    <input name="option[a][]" value="option a,1">
    <input name="option[b][]" value="option b,0" />
    <input name="option[b][]" value="option b,1" />
    <input name="option[]" value="option 0" />
</form>
```

Access this data like this:

```
<?php

echo $option['a'][0];
echo $option['a'][1];
echo $option['b'][0];
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim! I've read a bit about sessions (I'm a rookie with PHP) and I think they could be really useful for what I need... In this case, though, as I'm just creating a sort of quick prototype for a project, I'm gonna go with the "urlencode" solution, but I'll take a look at the sessions to learn more about them! :)